# Diamond Not compiling Java 7

Tags: java

I have defined the following generic Class , But when I use it on the Class Object it doesn't compile. The constructor wouldn't accept other object

```
class Pair<T,V> {

    T one;
    V two;


    public Pair(T one, V two) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }


}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String hamza = "Hamza";
    Integer soufiane = 0;

    Pair<Object,Object> pairOne = new Pair<>(hamza, soufiane);
    Pair<Object,Object> pairTwo = new Pair<Object, Object>(soufiane, hamza);

}
```

Error message:

```
incompatible types: Pair<String,Integer> cannot be converted to Pair<Object,Object>
```

Why did the first one not Compile and the second compile ?

**EDIT:** It compiled on Java 8

Comment: It is quite rare that something doesn't compile and the compiler doesn't tell you _why_ it doesn't compile.

Comment: i included the error message there! It's the diamond notation and it should compile, at least to my knowledge. Why it forced me to include the template parameters is what i don't understand.

Comment: Well, Generic Types aren't polymorph, so assigning `Pair<String,Integer>` to `Pair<Object,Object>` doesn't work and Java 7 think it should be `Pair<String,Integer>` because you said the passed arguments will tell the type. Java 8 on the other hand is a bit better with "finding" the correct generic type.

Comment: @Tom The point of the diamond notation is to match the left hand type which I clearly stated as `Pair<Object, Object>`, the constructor should take the parameters by casting them to `Object`.  I think matching the type by using the constructor isn't the logical thing here. I could have used an empty constructor and then set the members using setters.

Comment: @soufianefahid The point of the diamond is not to "match the left hand type", but simply to infer the type. Java 7 was much more limited in its ability to do this. In the Java 7 case, the type is being inferred from the arguments, not the left hand type.

Comment: @soufianefahid *"I could have used an empty constructor and then set the members using setters"* You could, but you didn't. And when you really do that, then you will see, then Java 7 will accept it.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Thanks! The word infer does make things clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Your code fail because the java 7 compiler can't find the proper inferred type; on the other hand java 8 would compile and work fine. (tl;dr: java 7 doesn't properly works with all diamonds, this was improved in java 8)

[JEP 101: Generalized Target-Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101)

> Smoothly expand the scope of method type-inference to support (i)
>   inference in method context and (ii) inference in chained calls.

Meaning java 8 would be able to determine the type of your call using the diamond operator.

**EDIT:** Looks like someone beat me to this reponse in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818287/why-does-the-diamond-operator-not-work-for-java-util-collections-methods-in-java) and explained it more clearly than me; so take a look !